# How to fill n rows based on a past value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Following is my dataset:

```
Name  Rate   Stock   
AB    32.8    0         
CD    56.7   100     
EF    34.7    0
GH    33.1    0      
IJ    44.5   100      
KL    33.6    0
```

I want to add another column `Discount` that is `0.95 * Rate`. However, it can only use `Rate` with `Stock = 100`. It should keep reiterating the `Discount` value until it finds the next `Stock = 100`

Here's my desired outcome:

```
Name   Rate   Stock   Discount 
AB     32.8    0         
CD     56.7   100       53.87
EF     34.7    0        53.87
GH     33.1    0        53.87
IJ     44.5   100       42.28
KL     33.6    0        42.28
```

Little help will be appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
df['Discount'] = df["Rate"][df["Stock"].eq(100)].mul(0.95) \
                                       .reindex(df.index).ffill()
```

```
>>> df
  Name  Rate  Stock  Discount
0   AB  32.8      0       NaN
1   CD  56.7    100    53.865
2   EF  34.7      0    53.865
3   GH  33.1      0    53.865
4   IJ  44.5    100    42.275
5   KL  33.6      0    42.275
```

Answer (score 2):

One way using boolean indexing with `ffill`:

```
df["Discount"] = df["Rate"][df["Stock"].eq(100)] * 0.95
df["Discount"] = df["Discount"].ffill().fillna("")
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Rate  Stock Discount
0  32.8      0         
1  56.7    100   53.865
2  34.7      0   53.865
3  33.1      0   53.865
4  44.5    100   42.275
5  33.6      0   42.275
```

Comment: My actual data also has a `string` column and gives out this error `ValueError: could not convert string to float: ...`

Comment: @Strugglingbrat I've updated answer to only modify related columns